# Is there a way to have a formula or script pick an amount of pre-set lengths to cover an area

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, linear-optimization

Apologies if the title isn't very clear.

What I am trying to do is get a google sheet to automatically calculate how many lengths of a material I will need to cover an area, hopefully to include a mix if needed. There are three different lengths of material that never change, but the total area I need to cover changes on a case by case basis. It is only a straight line so there is no need to worry about width or height.

The data breaks down as follows:
Pre-set lengths to choose from

- 10'6"
- 12'6"
- 14'6"

Length of area I need to cover only comes in inches (ie. 68 1/2"; 70"; 59")

The only thing I have been successful in doing is getting the length I need to cover and then manually picking out how many pieces of each length I need, but I cannot think of any way for me to have a formula or script optimize how many of each piece I need. I can understand formulas well enough, but once trying to script anything comes into play I start getting lost. I believe this issue may be beyond the capabilities of formulas.

Comment: Yes. Look into linear optimization engine. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Comment: In your example sizes they are all smaller than your smallest material so I’m assuming that is the sizes for a single project, your examples all add up to 197.5 inches would you prefer to order one of the largest and smallest or order two of the smallest? Waste percentage? Larger size discount? Do you throw out the unused portions?

Comment: convert to millimeters do math and convert back

Comment: @CodeCamper
So the three measurements I gave would all be for separate projects. I am trying to find the length of steel pieces needed for a roof. Specifically the rakes that go on the Gable end of a building. For example: if the measurement I am given is 50" then that is the length from the bottom of the gutter to the top of the roof peak, and I need to cover that distance four times (Down both sides of the roof on the N side of the building and both sides on the South) so I would need a grand total of 200" of material. I want to calculate the pieces needed to have the least waste and joins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting problem - I don't have the 'reputation' required to comment, but to be clear: you're actually trying to find the 'best fit' of the available lengths to cover the required length?
If that's the case then yes, you're not going to get there without scripting. Fortunately, there are other folks who have this problem and have solved it... you could look at [this online cut-list calculator](https://www.opticutter.com/linear-cut-list-calculator) for an example. I think that one even includes an embeddable script for your sheets.

If you're looking to solve the problem yourself because it's interesting, googling 'optimal cut list' or the like will turn up references. Usually you're optimizing on two variables (e.g. 'fewest joins' and 'least waste'), which tips you over into the world of linear programming (only just...) if you want to go there. If it were me, I'd just dig up a few example scripts and map how they operate back to a theoretical description (e.g. this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem).)

Comment: Interesting approach and solution.

Comment: Just glancing over this it seems like exactly what I am trying to do. The basic premise is to calculate how many pieces I need to cover that distance with the two variable you mentioned, least joins and least waste.

Comment: after playing around with it. The only cut-list calculator is exactly what I was looking for. I will still play around with the linear programming just to boost my skills. Thanks for the info!!